# Smoothing out parallax scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a header which is going to be twice the height of the viewport. When it gets to the end of the header, I've made a simple parallax effect which then reveals the content underneath, however, when you scroll, the content is flicking (I'm guessing because it's having calculate the scroll and adjust with css style "top:xxx"). Does anyone have any ideas on how I can smooth this out or have any tutorials which have similar functionality?

```js
$(window).scroll(function(e){
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var h = $(window).height()*2;
 if (scroll < h){
  $('#wrapper').css({'top':scroll })
 }
});
```

```css
#top {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  z-index:99;
  top:0;
  height: 200vh;
  background: red;
}
#wrapper {
  position:Relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="top"></div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tempus turpis ligula, ut sagittis ipsum dapibus sed. Proin ipsum risus, vulputate non mi dignissim, elementum commodo arcu. In tellus mauris, semper quis imperdiet quis, semper quis neque. Etiam dolor mi, feugiat non sem pharetra, porta molestie ligula. Pellentesque sed cursus enim, sed interdum ipsum. Donec eu sem eget lorem ullamcorper cursus. Fusce molestie tempor venenatis. Vivamus pellentesque blandit odio, at iaculis lorem ultricies id. Donec sollicitudin, risus eu vehicula faucibus, nisi nisl vestibulum magna, vel eleifend arcu ex ac quam. Duis fringilla tellus sit amet ipsum pulvinar, eu ultricies elit mattis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur vitae blandit nisi.
  </p>
  <p>
     Praesent placerat quam non dolor faucibus feugiat. Quisque rutrum pellentesque nulla id consequat. Nunc varius, tortor sed vehicula volutpat, nunc leo varius tellus, eu imperdiet magna lacus lobortis mauris. Maecenas dapibus massa et nunc porttitor, ac eleifend arcu euismod. Vestibulum malesuada ex facilisis erat sagittis, at hendrerit nibh imperdiet. Integer in tempus dui. Vestibulum a neque orci. Vestibulum vel purus at quam consequat iaculis nec at ligula. Fusce id iaculis elit. Suspendisse imperdiet quis turpis quis viverra. Suspendisse consequat dignissim leo, vel posuere felis dapibus at. Vivamus sed maximus dolor, ut pellentesque tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tempus turpis ligula, ut sagittis ipsum dapibus sed. Proin ipsum risus, vulputate non mi dignissim, elementum commodo arcu. In tellus mauris, semper quis imperdiet quis, semper quis neque. Etiam dolor mi, feugiat non sem pharetra, porta molestie ligula. Pellentesque sed cursus enim, sed interdum ipsum. Donec eu sem eget lorem ullamcorper cursus. Fusce molestie tempor venenatis. Vivamus pellentesque blandit odio, at iaculis lorem ultricies id. Donec sollicitudin, risus eu vehicula faucibus, nisi nisl vestibulum magna, vel eleifend arcu ex ac quam. Duis fringilla tellus sit amet ipsum pulvinar, eu ultricies elit mattis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur vitae blandit nisi.
  </p>
  <p>
    Praesent placerat quam non dolor faucibus feugiat. Quisque rutrum pellentesque nulla id consequat. Nunc varius, tortor sed vehicula volutpat, nunc leo varius tellus, eu imperdiet magna lacus lobortis mauris. Maecenas dapibus massa et nunc porttitor, ac eleifend arcu euismod. Vestibulum malesuada ex facilisis erat sagittis, at hendrerit nibh imperdiet. Integer in tempus dui. Vestibulum a neque orci. Vestibulum vel purus at quam consequat iaculis nec at ligula. Fusce id iaculis elit. Suspendisse imperdiet quis turpis quis viverra. Suspendisse consequat dignissim leo, vel posuere felis dapibus at. Vivamus sed maximus dolor, ut pellentesque tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tempus turpis ligula, ut sagittis ipsum dapibus sed. Proin ipsum risus, vulputate non mi dignissim, elementum commodo arcu. In tellus mauris, semper quis imperdiet quis, semper quis neque. Etiam dolor mi, feugiat non sem pharetra, porta molestie ligula. Pellentesque sed cursus enim, sed interdum ipsum. Donec eu sem eget lorem ullamcorper cursus. Fusce molestie tempor venenatis. Vivamus pellentesque blandit odio, at iaculis lorem ultricies id. Donec sollicitudin, risus eu vehicula faucibus, nisi nisl vestibulum magna, vel eleifend arcu ex ac quam. Duis fringilla tellus sit amet ipsum pulvinar, eu ultricies elit mattis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur vitae blandit nisi.
  </p>
  <p>
    Praesent placerat quam non dolor faucibus feugiat. Quisque rutrum pellentesque nulla id consequat. Nunc varius, tortor sed vehicula volutpat, nunc leo varius tellus, eu imperdiet magna lacus lobortis mauris. Maecenas dapibus massa et nunc porttitor, ac eleifend arcu euismod. Vestibulum malesuada ex facilisis erat sagittis, at hendrerit nibh imperdiet. Integer in tempus dui. Vestibulum a neque orci. Vestibulum vel purus at quam consequat iaculis nec at ligula. Fusce id iaculis elit. Suspendisse imperdiet quis turpis quis viverra. Suspendisse consequat dignissim leo, vel posuere felis dapibus at. Vivamus sed maximus dolor, ut pellentesque tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tempus turpis ligula, ut sagittis ipsum dapibus sed. Proin ipsum risus, vulputate non mi dignissim, elementum commodo arcu. In tellus mauris, semper quis imperdiet quis, semper quis neque. Etiam dolor mi, feugiat non sem pharetra, porta molestie ligula. Pellentesque sed cursus enim, sed interdum ipsum. Donec eu sem eget lorem ullamcorper cursus. Fusce molestie tempor venenatis. Vivamus pellentesque blandit odio, at iaculis lorem ultricies id. Donec sollicitudin, risus eu vehicula faucibus, nisi nisl vestibulum magna, vel eleifend arcu ex ac quam. Duis fringilla tellus sit amet ipsum pulvinar, eu ultricies elit mattis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur vitae blandit nisi.
  </p>
  <p>
    Praesent placerat quam non dolor faucibus feugiat. Quisque rutrum pellentesque nulla id consequat. Nunc varius, tortor sed vehicula volutpat, nunc leo varius tellus, eu imperdiet magna lacus lobortis mauris. Maecenas dapibus massa et nunc porttitor, ac eleifend arcu euismod. Vestibulum malesuada ex facilisis erat sagittis, at hendrerit nibh imperdiet. Integer in tempus dui. Vestibulum a neque orci. Vestibulum vel purus at quam consequat iaculis nec at ligula. Fusce id iaculis elit. Suspendisse imperdiet quis turpis quis viverra. Suspendisse consequat dignissim leo, vel posuere felis dapibus at. Vivamus sed maximus dolor, ut pellentesque tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Seems to be working fine for me on Chrome.

Comment: That's very interesting! I guess I can't help you so because I don't have a retina display... I wonder what percentage of your site users will be using retina though? Is it worth your while to fix?

Comment: Is it the font that's flickering? Try using a different font as outlined in this article... https://www.sitepoint.com/support-retina-displays/

Comment: Im on chrome, mac and I see the flickering...

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue you are talking about on Mac in Chrome.

You can fix the "stuttering" with:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Your code with new lines of code implemented:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(e){
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var h = $(window).height()*2;
 if (scroll < h){
  $('#wrapper').css({'top':scroll })
 }
});
```

```css
#top {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  z-index:99;
  top:0;
  height: 200vh;
  background: red;
}
#wrapper {
  position:Relative;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="top"></div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tempus turpis ligula, ut sagittis ipsum dapibus sed. Proin ipsum risus, vulputate non mi dignissim, elementum commodo arcu. In tellus mauris, semper quis imperdiet quis, semper quis neque. Etiam dolor mi, feugiat non sem pharetra, porta molestie ligula. Pellentesque sed cursus enim, sed interdum ipsum. Donec eu sem eget lorem ullamcorper cursus. Fusce molestie tempor venenatis. Vivamus pellentesque blandit odio, at iaculis lorem ultricies id. Donec sollicitudin, risus eu vehicula faucibus, nisi nisl vestibulum magna, vel eleifend arcu ex ac quam. Duis fringilla tellus sit amet ipsum pulvinar, eu ultricies elit mattis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur vitae blandit nisi.
  </p>
  <p>
     Praesent placerat quam non dolor faucibus feugiat. Quisque rutrum pellentesque nulla id consequat. Nunc varius, tortor sed vehicula volutpat, nunc leo varius tellus, eu imperdiet magna lacus lobortis mauris. Maecenas dapibus massa et nunc porttitor, ac eleifend arcu euismod. Vestibulum malesuada ex facilisis erat sagittis, at hendrerit nibh imperdiet. Integer in tempus dui. Vestibulum a neque orci. Vestibulum vel purus at quam consequat iaculis nec at ligula. Fusce id iaculis elit. Suspendisse imperdiet quis turpis quis viverra. Suspendisse consequat dignissim leo, vel posuere felis dapibus at. Vivamus sed maximus dolor, ut pellentesque tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tempus turpis ligula, ut sagittis ipsum dapibus sed. Proin ipsum risus, vulputate non mi dignissim, elementum commodo arcu. In tellus mauris, semper quis imperdiet quis, semper quis neque. Etiam dolor mi, feugiat non sem pharetra, porta molestie ligula. Pellentesque sed cursus enim, sed interdum ipsum. Donec eu sem eget lorem ullamcorper cursus. Fusce molestie tempor venenatis. Vivamus pellentesque blandit odio, at iaculis lorem ultricies id. Donec sollicitudin, risus eu vehicula faucibus, nisi nisl vestibulum magna, vel eleifend arcu ex ac quam. Duis fringilla tellus sit amet ipsum pulvinar, eu ultricies elit mattis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur vitae blandit nisi.
  </p>
  <p>
    Praesent placerat quam non dolor faucibus feugiat. Quisque rutrum pellentesque nulla id consequat. Nunc varius, tortor sed vehicula volutpat, nunc leo varius tellus, eu imperdiet magna lacus lobortis mauris. Maecenas dapibus massa et nunc porttitor, ac eleifend arcu euismod. Vestibulum malesuada ex facilisis erat sagittis, at hendrerit nibh imperdiet. Integer in tempus dui. Vestibulum a neque orci. Vestibulum vel purus at quam consequat iaculis nec at ligula. Fusce id iaculis elit. Suspendisse imperdiet quis turpis quis viverra. Suspendisse consequat dignissim leo, vel posuere felis dapibus at. Vivamus sed maximus dolor, ut pellentesque tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tempus turpis ligula, ut sagittis ipsum dapibus sed. Proin ipsum risus, vulputate non mi dignissim, elementum commodo arcu. In tellus mauris, semper quis imperdiet quis, semper quis neque. Etiam dolor mi, feugiat non sem pharetra, porta molestie ligula. Pellentesque sed cursus enim, sed interdum ipsum. Donec eu sem eget lorem ullamcorper cursus. Fusce molestie tempor venenatis. Vivamus pellentesque blandit odio, at iaculis lorem ultricies id. Donec sollicitudin, risus eu vehicula faucibus, nisi nisl vestibulum magna, vel eleifend arcu ex ac quam. Duis fringilla tellus sit amet ipsum pulvinar, eu ultricies elit mattis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur vitae blandit nisi.
  </p>
  <p>
    Praesent placerat quam non dolor faucibus feugiat. Quisque rutrum pellentesque nulla id consequat. Nunc varius, tortor sed vehicula volutpat, nunc leo varius tellus, eu imperdiet magna lacus lobortis mauris. Maecenas dapibus massa et nunc porttitor, ac eleifend arcu euismod. Vestibulum malesuada ex facilisis erat sagittis, at hendrerit nibh imperdiet. Integer in tempus dui. Vestibulum a neque orci. Vestibulum vel purus at quam consequat iaculis nec at ligula. Fusce id iaculis elit. Suspendisse imperdiet quis turpis quis viverra. Suspendisse consequat dignissim leo, vel posuere felis dapibus at. Vivamus sed maximus dolor, ut pellentesque tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tempus turpis ligula, ut sagittis ipsum dapibus sed. Proin ipsum risus, vulputate non mi dignissim, elementum commodo arcu. In tellus mauris, semper quis imperdiet quis, semper quis neque. Etiam dolor mi, feugiat non sem pharetra, porta molestie ligula. Pellentesque sed cursus enim, sed interdum ipsum. Donec eu sem eget lorem ullamcorper cursus. Fusce molestie tempor venenatis. Vivamus pellentesque blandit odio, at iaculis lorem ultricies id. Donec sollicitudin, risus eu vehicula faucibus, nisi nisl vestibulum magna, vel eleifend arcu ex ac quam. Duis fringilla tellus sit amet ipsum pulvinar, eu ultricies elit mattis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur vitae blandit nisi.
  </p>
  <p>
    Praesent placerat quam non dolor faucibus feugiat. Quisque rutrum pellentesque nulla id consequat. Nunc varius, tortor sed vehicula volutpat, nunc leo varius tellus, eu imperdiet magna lacus lobortis mauris. Maecenas dapibus massa et nunc porttitor, ac eleifend arcu euismod. Vestibulum malesuada ex facilisis erat sagittis, at hendrerit nibh imperdiet. Integer in tempus dui. Vestibulum a neque orci. Vestibulum vel purus at quam consequat iaculis nec at ligula. Fusce id iaculis elit. Suspendisse imperdiet quis turpis quis viverra. Suspendisse consequat dignissim leo, vel posuere felis dapibus at. Vivamus sed maximus dolor, ut pellentesque tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but even with the backface-visibility: hidden; property it's still stuttering

Comment: @FrazerFindlater hmmmm why dont you make it so the `top` moves instead of the whole `wrapper`?

Comment: Yeah I've been trying to find a way to just move the top and keep the content in place but I haven't been to successful pulling it off.

Comment: @FrazerFindlater one other thing: I just realised that when I took the code out of a snippet and put it into an actual page it worked fine have you done that too? like here for example: https://jsfiddle.net/mmh6z61f/

Comment: Yeah that's the frustrating part. I've got a fiddle of it working fine too - https://jsfiddle.net/t9ar1hrc/ - but when I actually put it on the page where it's suppose to go it starts flickering. It's driving me mad!

Comment: @FrazerFindlater what about something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/t9ar1hrc/1/ :)